# Where does Chrome store the list of recently opened tabs on iPadOS?

Tags: google-chrome, ipad

I just updated both an iPhone and an iPad Pro from the last 15.x OS to 16.2. After the update, the iPhone kept my current Chrome tabs open. But on the iPad, Chrome closed all of my open tabs (over 100). I'd like to either re-open those tabs en masse, or recover a list of the URLs for them. I do have a backup of the iPad just prior to the update (via iMazing on macOS), which might enable accessing an open tabs list from prior to the update.

In an effort to access the info, I used *Google Takeout* to export my Chrome info that Google has stored in the cloud. I can find my history in the export (as a JSON file), and I've written a Python script to convert it to a web page of URLs. But there are thousands of URLs in my history, not just the ~100+ visited websites that had open tabs. As far as I can tell, *Google Takeout* does not offer an export of recently opened tabs. And I don't see any attributes in the history JSON data distinguishing URLs for closed tabs from open ones.

In Chrome on the updated iPad, I have access to a <kbd>Recent Tabs</kbd> list via the 3-dot menu. But it only allows opening the tabs one at a time (with multiple interactions required for each one, since the list gets closed even when a tab is opened in the background). If I could access whatever data Chrome is accessing to build its <kbd>Recent Tabs</kbd> list, I could access my lost tabs that way. But I don't know where that information is stored (presumably somewhere like the profile directory visible on macOS). Any direction on where to look would be appreciated.

A previous question from a macOS Chrome user is related: [macos - How to restore Chrome's list of recently closed tabs - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/610281/how-to-restore-chromes-list-of-recently-closed-tabs). It indicates that, on macOS, a `Current Tabs` file in Chrome's default session folder holds this type of data. Is there a counterpart for iPadOS that I could access in my pre-update backup?